# Change manually the icon of a nautilus place item

Tags: nautilus, icons, gconf

I've added some of my sftp to nautilus but there is no option to change the icon of the marker, since nautilis adds directly to the places section. I searched for a gconf config but didn't found.

Example (INF-UFG SFTP is the folder/marker icon that I want to change):

[image: Places]

Comment: These are not stored in gconf I believe. Also I don't think you can change icons for entries that are automatically added in that manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to change the icon in the system folder and name your new one the same as the old it would be a good idea to keep your old icon incase you wanted to change it back

icons are stored in

```
/usr/share/icons/
```

then there are a few more folders first 1 will be your icon theme then the next are icon sizes

also you may be able to change the icon path in the .desktop file these are usually in

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

or in

```
~/.local/share/applications/
```

Comment: Downvoted but no comment to say why thats really helpfull

Comment: The reason for the downvote is due to the fact that the shortcut uses the default folder icon of the icon theme. Changing, would change not only it's shortcut but

Comment: ok then the entry were the arrow is pointing to with the eject button could be changed with an autorun file pointing to the location of the icon the one labeled INF-UFG SFTP if it is a shortcut to a folder will only have the default folder icon due to a bug it has been fixed but only in nautilus 3 see here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/423890